# What is the probability that the first digit of a random $2$ digit integer is smaller than the second?

Tags: probability

> What is the probability that the first digit of a random $2$ digit integer is smaller than the second?

Let $A=$ $\{$first digit is smaller than the second$\}$. The total number of $2$ digit integers is $n=99-10+1=90$. We have to find the number of trials. I am trying to make it without writing all the numbers. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: The first digit is $\{1,\cdots, 9\}$ with equal probability. The second is $\{0,\cdots,9\}$ with equal probability.  The computation isn't difficult.

Comment: I didn't get this.

Comment: Pick a first digit, say $6$.  In order for the second digit to be less than $6$ it must be  one of $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, hence probability $\frac 6{10}$.  And so on.

Answer (score 3):

The probability is $1/2$.

Consider number from $10$ to $20$.

You have only one number $10$ whose one digit is less than $10$'s digit.

From $20$ to $30$ you have $2$.

The series will be of AP with series of 1, 2, 3, 4 _ _ _ ,9.

So the probability is $45/90$.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the list of integers $\{10,...20,...99\}$. Obvilusly there are 10×9=90 such values. In the first 10 values exactly 1 second digit is less than the first. In the second 2, etc and in the last 8 such values. $1+2+\ldots 8= \frac{9×8}{2} =36$. So the probability is ${36}{90}$. To get the 0.5 probability you need to add the condition 'less or equal' to arrive at $\frac{45}{90}$.